# How to get data from aws Dynamodb with using partition key only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am using aws-sdk-go library for DynamoDb connectivity in Golang.

My DynamoDb table have a Partition key DeviceId (String) and a Sort Key Time (Number). How can I write GetItemInput to get all data with a specific DeviceId?

```
params := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{

    Key:    map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue {
        "DeviceId": {
            S: aws.String("item_1"),
        },
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
        "DeviceId": "DeviceId",
    },
    TableName:  aws.String("DbName"), 
}

list, err := svc.GetItem(params)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use Query or Scan operation, this is a simple example but you can read more on Amazon documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)

In particular, Query operation

> > A Query operation finds items in a table or a secondary index using only primary key attribute values

```
var queryInput = &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName: aws.String(dynamoRestDataTableName),
    KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
        "DeviceId": {
            ComparisonOperator: aws.String("EQ"),
            AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                {
                    S: aws.String("aDeviceId"),
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

var resp, err = dynamoSvc.Query(queryInput)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. Can you please tell me how to access data from the QueryOutput? Suppose if I want to access last entry in the queryoutput how can I do that?

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? `*resp.Items[*resp.Count - int64(1)]["attribute"].S`

Comment: This looks perfect Alessio except it should be `S: aws.String("aDeviceId"),`

Comment: @user6681013 if we look in `api.go` we can see that the `QueryOutput` struct has the definition `Items []map[string]*AttributeValue` so the results are returned as an array of maps. each map represents one row of values and each key in the map represents one column name in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Query operation can be used in that case
Following is one generic example for the same

```
compositeKey := entity.GetPrimaryKey(inputVar)
expressionAttributeValues := map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
    ":v1": {
        S: aws.String(compositeKey.PartitionKey.Data.(string)),
    },
}
queryInput := dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName:                 &d.TableName,
    KeyConditionExpression:    aws.String("id = :v1"),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
}
queryOutput, err := d.DdbSession.Query(&queryInput)
if err != nil {
    log.Error("error in fetching records ", err)
    return nil, err
}

// unmarshal the query output - items to interface

err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(queryOutput.Items, &yourInterface)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getItem in JavaScript SDK v2 like this

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'tableName',
    Key: {
        id: { S: id },
    },
};

const result = await dynamoDb.getItem(params).promise();
if (result.Item === undefined) {
    throw new Error('not found');
}
const item = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(result.Item)
```

If JavaScript SDK can do this, I assume golang SDK can also. If not, that means AWS doesn't take all languages equally ?